# How to pass param value dynamically to custom annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties, annotations

I am using a library which has below custom annotation created.

```java
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@DependsOn({"springBeanUtils"})
public @interface PartyCacheable {
    boolean enable() default false;
}
```

Below is the snippet where I am using above annotation

```java
@PartyCacheable(enable = false)       // this value needs to be toggled from property value 
public class PartyProcessing {

// some implementation

}
```

Is there a way to toggle PartyCacheable annotation with true and false based from the application.properties file ?

```
party.cache.enable=true
```

Answer (score 0):

No you can not use annotations with properties. Annotations have to be used with constant values.

Comment: any workaround ?

Comment: Use Factory Class for PartyProcessing Class which returns an implementation with annotation and desired value. To choose your desired implementation you could use a self defined property.